# How to clear the Photos icon badge

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

For some reason that is not clear to me, the Photos app icon on the dock of my Yosemite OS now displays a badge (the number 1 in a red circle top right corner)

First of all, I have no idea what that badge is suppose to represent.  Second, when I launch the app I have not idea what the thing is that I'm suppose to look at, acknowledge or in some way "touch" so that the badge goes away.

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't already, turn on the sidebar - <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> - then look towards the top and under Shared, click Activity. Likely there is some activity on a shared album or Photo Stream. It may also be someone inviting you to join a shared album or Photo Stream. (I'm not sure how that would show up in Photos, as I haven't had any invitations since Photos was released.)

Either way I'm guessing once you take a look at that area, the badge will disappear.

Comment: I have the same question, and don't see "shared" in the sidebar. Any other suggestions? And I don't have any shared folders using photos...

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you're talking about iOS, the badge may mean somebody commented or liked one of your photos on a shared folder.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the exact name for the shared folder or photo stream but I have Spanish as my language on my iPhone.

Comment: No I'm referring specifically to the photos app that replaces iPhoto on Yosemite

Comment: Ok, please clarify on your question, it will be easier to answer.

Comment: I've added Yosemite to the text of my question, although I want to point out that the original post was tagged as a yosemite question.

Comment: Great, I just thought it may disambiguate the OS you were referring to. I did not see the Yosemite tag at the time, my bad.

Comment: Did you find out what the badge was after turning on the sidebar?

Comment: Yes it was a "Like" added to a shared photo by one of my family members

Comment: I have the same problem, showing a tiny red bubble (with a more tiny 1) on my Macs dock. I do not use iCloud or other sharing. The "Activity" button only suggests to share my Photos, but the badge does not disappear!?